# Как количество строк SQLite перевести в Integer

Tags: php

С помощью команды `$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM translate")` узнал количество столбцов в таблице SQLite, но как его перевести в Integer для того чтобы использовать в цикле? Если `$result` вывести с помощью `$row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC); var_dump($row);` то он выводит 
 `C:\wamp64\www\syst.php:11: array (size=1) 'COUNT(*)' => int 4` в конце написано количество столбцов но как его вытащить для цикла?

Comment: `$result['COUNT(*)']`. А если задать псведоним в запросе `...COUNT(*) as translate_count...`, то `$result['translate_count']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью команды `$result['COUNT(*)']`